# HANA: Error while creating R Procedure

Tags: r, procedure, hana

I am trying to create a procedure in HANA which uses R code. As a result I want to get the missing values counted. I tried the R code in R Studio and it works:

```
 DROP Table "THESIS"."THESIS_FOLDER::COUNT_MISSING_VALUES"; 
 CREATE Column TABLE "THESIS"."THESIS_FOLDER::COUNT_MISSING_VALUES" (RESULT" INT  );

 DROP PROCEDURE "THESIS"."ANALYSE_MISSINGDATA"; 
 Create PROCEDURE "THESIS"."ANALYSE_MISSINGDATA" (IN input _SYS_BIC"."THESIS_FOLDER/CA_SAMPLE", OUT OUTPUT_DATA   "THESIS"."THESIS_FOLDER::COUNT_MISSING_VALUE" ) 
 LANGUAGE RLANG AS
 BEGIN

 result<-sapply(input, function(x) sum(is.na(x)))
 OUTPUT_DATA<-data.frame(RESULT=result)

 END;

 Call "THESIS"."ANALYSE_MISSINGDATA"("_SYS_BIC"."THESIS_FOLDER/CA_SAMPLE",?);
```

But when I try this I get the following error:
SAP DBTech JDBC: [2048]: column store error: search table error:  [34084] Receive error: get result error.;Failure: Object 'output_data' not found.

Does anybody know what I did wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause for the error message is that you refer to your output variable in UPPER case letters. 
Check the ["SAP HANA R Integration Guide"](https://help.sap.com/viewer/a78d7f701c3341339fafe4031b64f015/2.0.01/en-US)/d867885b48b0480a81f0e61818eafcf1.html):

> The variable names from the procedure definition should not contain uppercase letters. Therefore, the variable names in R should also not contain upper-case letters

Just change the `OUTPUT_DATA<-data.frame(RESULT=result)` to `output_data<-data.frame(RESULT=result)` and your code should work.